# Compass/Susy Disable automatic clearfix?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I'm using Compass/Susy for the first time. I'm having an issue when using the @include container mixin. It's automatically applying a clearfix to it. This is not desired. Is there a way to turn this off, or override it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can fork the [source of susy](https://github.com/ericam/susy/) and change this file:
https://github.com/ericam/susy/blob/master/sass/susy/_grid.scss

It looks like the pie-clearfix is applied in this mixin: `@mixin apply-container`

There might be a way to over-write mixins... Or just make another one that is similar to this one - and call that instead.

Comment: Assuming the OP *never* wants to use the `pie-clearfix` mixin elsewhere (comes from Compass, not Susy), declaring another one that does nothing would work just fine.

Comment: You could also simply override the clearfix. I bet something like `&:after { display: none; clear: none; }` would take care of it, without needing to touch the Susy core code. File an issue on github, and we can consider making this optional in 2.0.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using an override similar to Eric's suggestion.